# Did I commit shirk in my mind by saying a shirk statement due to waswas?

Tags: shirk, kufr

I have waswas, but I sometimes try to stop these thoughts but don't succeed, so I end up saying a shirk/kufr statement in my mind. But I immediately repent and tauba, I don't mean anything and don't believe in anything. I asked my mother, she said it's ok and I haven't done shirk, because shirk is only done when a person believes in it and purposely says it, and that shaytaan sends these and it's ok if one isnt able to stop his mind to saying this. My mind says it and I just am not able to stop it sometimes. Am I sinful? Please tell me it isn't.